# Refactoring java classes where methods have different parameter types

Tags: java, refactoring, abstract-class

I have two classes that `extend` an abstract class in a very similar manner, and I'd like to abstract out the common parts since I will likely have to use this again. They each return a `ThingLink` containing data linking them to a `Parent` object. They also return a `Widget` that varies based on the class, but only up to their name. Here is the pattern:

```
public abstract class SomeClass extends TopClass {
    protected abstract Widget createWidget();

    public void someMethod() { // Does something }
}

public class ThingA extends SomeClass {

    private static final String INFO_TYPE = "int";

    public ThingLink newLink(Parent master, Int info) {
        ThingLink link = new ThingLink(parent, ThingA.class);
        link.addData(INFO_TYPE, info);
        return link;
    }

    public Widget createWidget() {
        // Stuff to get someData
        return ThingAWidget.createMe(someData);
    }
}

public class ThingB extends SomeClass {

    private static final String INFO_TYPE = "String";

    public ThingLink newLink(Parent master, String info) {
        ThingLink link = new ThingLink(parent, ThingB.class);
        link.addData(INFO_TYPE, info);
        return link;
    }

    public Widget createWidget() {
        // Stuff to get someData
        return ThingBWidget.createMe(someData);
    }
}
```

I have no access to `TopClass`, the `ThingLink` class, or the `Widget` class. I was trying to abstract out the common parts using generics, but I can't seem to figure out if that will provide a complete solution. My big problem is figuring out how to get the pieces that are self-referential. I would like a class something like:

```
public abstract class Thing<T> extends SomeClass {
    private String infoType;

    public void setInfoType(String type) { infoType = type; }

    public ThingLink newLink(Parent master, T info {
        ThingLink link = new ThingLink(parent, ???????????);
        link.addData(infoType, info);
        return link;
    }

    public Widget createWidget() {
        // Stuff to get someData
        return ??????????????.createMe(someData);
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that I am fairly new to Java, and self-taught, but I am trying very hard to make some bigger leaps and really understand how to write good code. I appreciate your help.

Comment: `???????????` in `ThingLink link = new ThingLink(parent, ???????????);` is actually quite easy - it is `this.getClass()`, isn't it?

Comment: Next, I don't think abstracting `createWidget` is reasonable. It's a one-liner implementation, you won't get it much better. One possible implementation would be to pass `Function<SomeData, Widget>` as `ThingXWidget::createMe` to the superclass. But that won't make things better.

Comment: Ahhh, I should have though of `getClass()`. I think that gets me the `newLink` method. And thanks for the help with `createWidget`, I was hoping it was a pattern that might be common enough to have a solution I wasn't aware of.

Comment: Why is widget creation in the separate `ThingXWidget` class anyway?

Comment: `ThingXWidget` extends `Widget` and gets created via `createMe` where it is returned by `createWidget` then used in `TopClass.someMethod`. The idea is to keep the details of each component hidden from each other to keep everything as reusable as possible. Incidentally the real classes are all android: `TopClass` = `AppCompatActivity`, `Widget` = `Fragment`, `ThingLink` = `Intent`, `someMethod` = `onCreate` etc.  I just wanted to keep those details out since they don't really effect the pattern.